# Update huge data in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake-task

i have a model named `PageDensity` which has about 5m rows.

When i created project `PageDensity` table stored float of 5 decimal precision in `density` coulmn.

Now the requirement changed to round it to two decimal places.

I simply wrote a task to round all the `densities` but it makes system so heavy that is stucks. Even i can't use `query` as my rounding is bit change like `0.57500` will be rounded to `0.57` and  `0.57600` will be rounded to `0.58`.

what i have tried so far is simply:

```
  task round_densities: :environment do
    application_object = ApplicationController.new
    time = Benchmark.realtime do
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        PageDensity.all.each {|p| p.update_attributes(density: application_object.round_number(p.density))}
      end
    end
    puts '***************************************'
    puts "Total Time Consumed #{time} seconds"
    puts '***************************************'
  end
```

and i also tried to make query for rounding but failed:

```
select round(0.00500, 2)
#this returns 0.01 as this should return 0.00
```

I am using `postgres` any idea to make it `psql query` or by using `rails` ?

Comment: I highly recommend you change `.all.each` with `.all.find_each` this way it will be done in batches

Comment: @apneadiving nice catch thanks. that would sure make difference but not that much

Comment: @Matt i tried but i was unable to make such rounding query. coz that is different from just normal rounding query as i explained it in question

Comment: I see. I don't quite understand your rounding logic, though. Do you simply need to truncate the last 3 digits?

Comment: @Matt no. `0.00100 to 0.00500` would be rounded down i-e `0.00`. and `0.00600 to 0.00900` would be rounded up i-e `0.01`. hope this makes sense

Comment: You can write your own rounding proc in postgres

Comment: @lx00st see the edit. i have added what i have tried to make query

Comment: I mean that instead of using `pg` built in round utils you can write your own stored procedure to round numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your rounding requirement is just 0.001 off what the normal rounding would be.

In which case I think you can run the sql update:

```
update page_densities set density = round(density - 0.001, 2)
```

This will round like this:

```
0.011 => round(0.010, 2) => 0.01
0.015 => round(0.014, 2) => 0.01
0.016 => round(0.015, 2) => 0.02
0.02  => round(0.019, 2) => 0.02
```

Comment: seem legit. let me try

Comment: this still takes 29 minutes for 628391 records. any idea to further improve it ?

Comment: No brainwaves I'm afraid. You've going to have to go over all the records one way or another. Only quick win would be if `density` doesn't always have a value and then you could filter using `where density is not null` - however given your column and table names that seems unlikely to be the case.

Comment: bad luck there is always some value in that `field`

Answer (score 2):

You should work with batches so change

```
PageDensity.all.each
```

with:

```
PageDensity.all.find_each
```

Check [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html).

But to do so, you'd have to remove the transaction which is actually useless.

---

Sideremark, if you have no callback to trigger, replace:

```
p.update_attributes(density: application_object.round_number(p.density))
```

with:

```
p.update_column(:density, application_object.round_number(p.density))
```

This will save some additional time.

Comment: Why do you say the transaction is useless?

Comment: Seems to me no integrity issue would arise from a failure. All elements are independent

Comment: this just reduces the memory usage. but will not change the time taken.

Comment: Not really, since loading everything in memory at once would slow everything down

Comment: `update_attribute` will still trigger callbacks (but not validation) and will modify `updated_at`. `update_column` will not trigger or update anything else (assuming rails  >= 3.1).

Comment: @apneadiving np - they changed it - I always have to check now

Comment: Maybe executing raw SQL is a good idea, because ActiveRecord eats up more memory and thus requires more GC. I would just run this SQL statement: update page_densities set density = round(density - 0.001, 2)

Comment: raw sql is always better than orm operations, for sure, my answer just optimizes the orm path

Comment: thanks for the rails way. that was helpful but query is better solution than that